# NSCollectionView select items for segue in OS X

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I have looked at the NSCollectionView API and I havnt found anything matching certain tutorials I have seen.  Xcode forces me to write my method like this so that there are no errors:

```
@objc(collectionView:didSelectItemsAtIndexPaths:) func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, didSelectItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>) {
    print("Selected")
}
```

Whenever I click on an item in my NSCollectionView nothing happens and my print statement never shows in the console.  What is the correct way to select an item from a NSCollectionView?

Comment: Have you set the collectionView's delegate?

Comment: Yes I have it set in extension ViewController: NSCollectionViewDelegate and it still doesn't print anything to the console.

Comment: I'd be inclined to put a `print` in the code after setting the delegate, as the most likely cause is that it's not actually set. I wouldn't expect you'd have to put the `@objc` part in either - what error are you getting without it? It might be helpful if you include all the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: I got it to work without the @obj part in front of it but it is still not printing "Selected"  in the console whenever I click on an item.  What could possibly be the reason for this.  This is really holding me back for something that would seem so simple.

Comment: I am dumb...I didn't drag my collectionViewDelegate to connect to my ViewController.  I am new to xCode and having to do all this dragging to set stuff up throws me off sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the property isSelectAble = true,like this:

```
self.collectionView. isSelectAble = true
```